# Object Selection error with Rebar inside concrete objects

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have 2 concrete beams drawn side by side.
One beam has the rebar set to be displayed as solid and unobscured.
The sencond beam has the rebar set as lines.

If I select the concrete of Beam 1 to hide, it selects fine
If I try to select the concrete on beam 2 it selects the rebar.

Fix is to turn of Lines in Viewer Settings.

[image: Revit Beam 1]

[image: Revit Beam 2]

[image: Select Concrete works fine]

[image: Select Concrete and I get Rebar]

Comment: I'm not sure how we can help here... do you need a confirmation or another way to solve this?

Comment: Are you addressing an issue that you cannot make the 2nd beam be selected while clicking on the concrete beam after hiding the concrete beam with solid-displayed rebar, i.e. only the strips become highlighted in the 2nd one? My model is put here (https://extract.autodesk.io/explore/6004736-rebarrvt), please check if it's the same as you're facing.

Comment: The second beam will not select... Only the rebar inside it

Comment: Ok, the behavior you observed is the same as I saw. I'll check with our engineering team, and get back to you A.S.A.P.

Comment: Sorry for letting you wait. After some investigation, I found that this issue only shows up with Viewer v4.x and lower. In v5.0, the click behavior works properly with the same model. Could you have a try? @user6628265